# How to boot into Windows 8.1 using safemode?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, safe-mode

I changed a setting on my Windows 8.1 PC and now the screen has gone black. Ive tried to get into safe mode using F8 / Shift-F8 but it never gives me safe mode.

All the guides on how to get into safe mode just state to do it through windows but as i disabled GPU Scaling on my AMD graphics card the screen is just black. I need to get into safe mode and re-enable GPU Scaling.

I've tried booting from Windows 8.1 disc and used repair PC that didn't work.

Also i tried restoring to an earlier version but that didn't work keeps saying cannot restore.

Really hope i don't have reformat the drive.

Anyone got any advice?

Comment: That guide says to use Shift+F8 which i tried and doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, the Shift-F8 only works on slow computers (if that).  Doesn't make it a different question though, we just need a better answer on the dupe.

Comment: So my only option is to format and re install the OS?

Comment: You say you booted from the disk and hit "repair PC", but it 'didn't work'. What "didn't work" exactly?  Did you see/choose the "Repair your computer" link, and did you not get the Advanced Startup Options screen once you chose it? If not, what happened exactly?

Comment: "I changed a setting..." What did you change, *exactly*?

Comment: i changed a setting on the AMD Drivers, Turned GPU Scaling off, which made a black screen. Seems alot of people have the same issue. @techie007 - I tried to roll back to a previous point neither of the points i could roll back to worked. I also tried the automatic repair that didn't work. By "didn't" work i mean it didn't give me the option to reboot into safe mode.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft changed it because they believe that Windows 8 starts so quickly you don't have time to press F8.
From: [Windows Startup Settings (including safe mode)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode)

> There are two ways to get to the Windows Startup Settings screen in
>   Windows 8 :
>
> - If you're not signed in to Windows, tap or click the power icon Power
>     icon from the sign-in screen, hold Shift, and then tap or click
>     Restart
> - Or, if you're already signed in:
>
>   1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap
>        Change PC settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right
>        corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click Settings, and
>        then click Change PC settings.)
>   2. Under PC settings, tap or click General.
>   3. Under Advanced startup, tap or click Restart now.
>   4. On the Choose an option screen, tap or click Troubleshoot.
>   5. Tap or click Startup Settings.
>   6. Tap or click Restart.
>   7. On the Startup Settings screen, choose the startup setting you want.
>   8. Sign in to your PC with a user account that has administrator rights.

---

If all else fails, you may be able to reset your GPU scaling settings by directly accessing the registry from the repair console command prompt.

[This forum post](http://forums.amd.com/gaming/messageview.cfm?catid=461&threadid=126667) suggests that zeroing out a couple of keys may fix your problem. You can use the [REG ADD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742162.aspx) command to accomplish this.

Comment: Both of these require you to be in windows already.

Comment: try issuing the command "shutdown /r /o" from the repair disc command prompt. That might get you to the advanced startup options.

Comment: Three failed attempts to load windows and this advanced menu will be offered